# Python - Finding the difference between 2 numbers

Tags: python, conditional-statements

So I'm trying to find a way to find the difference between 3 ints;
a, b, c
so I need to find the difference between a - b and the difference between b - c
and then print true if the difference is the same, else printing false.
I've been attempting to use the abs() function but can't seem to get the result I need. any help would be appreciated.

Here is the problem statement:

*Given three ints, a b c, one of them is small, one is medium and

one is large. Print True if the three values are evenly spaced, 
so the difference between small and medium is the same as the 
difference between medium and large.*

this is what i have so far;

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())

if abs(a-b) == abs(b-c) :
    print("True")
else :
    print("False")
```

## #

```
Test Input  Expected Actual 
1     4 6 2    True  False
2     6 2 4    True  False
3   10 9 11    True  False
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Does the code not do what you expected? If so, what input are you providing, what output did you expect, and what output did you actually get?

Comment: What is your desired output? What input(s) have you tried and how are they not similar to what you were expecting?

Comment: Never add spaces before colons. Also, this doesn't come across as the most idiomatic Python snippets I've seen, so you probably want to note the kind of design patterns Python developers use and follow those instead.

Comment: I just tested your code, and it works for integers. I'm guessing it fails when you try to input floats?

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information I'm going to edit my question

Comment: I don't understand your input - how is the expected result for `4 6 2` true when (4-6)=2 and (6-2)=4?

Comment: @lordingtar: Because the problem is that the code doesn't implement the problem statement.

Comment: @Tyson Based on the problem description, it sounds like you need to sort the inputs first.

Comment: You're treating a, b, and c like they are sorted in ascending order, that is, a < b < c. The spec only says that one will be small, one large, and one in between, so sorting them before testing ensures you're testing the absolute value between the middle one and the sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the problem description, it sounds like you need to sort the numbers first:

```
numbers = sorted(int(input()) for _ in range(3))
print(numbers[1] - numbers[0] == numbers[2] - numbers[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 possible "middle" numbers, therefore you need to perform 3 comparisons.

```
x = abs(a - b)
y = abs(a - c)
z = abs(b - c)
if (x == y) or (x == z) or (y == z):
   ...
```